# Why would my test class throw a Duplicate exception?

Tags: unit-test, user-record

I have a test class. The annotation on the class is `@isTest(SeeAllData=false)`

In the test, the first step I do is create a user.
I am getting the following exception when I run my test.

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: DUPLICATE_COMM_NICKNAME, Duplicate Nickname.
> Another user
>   has already selected this nickname.
> Please select another.:
>   [CommunityNickname]

If SeeAllData is set to false, why would I get a duplicate nickname exception? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With V24.0 and higher, certain SObjects used in Org Setup are available to test methods even if `SeeAllData=false`.  From the doc:

```
User
Profile
Organization
AsyncApexJob
CronTrigger
RecordType
ApexClass
ApexTrigger
ApexComponent
ApexPage
```

So, if your testmethod mocks a new user with a nickname already in use, it will be detected as a duplicate.

To avoid this, I tend to set mock User names, emails, aliases, nicknames, etc with leading or trailing special character like  `_` which is unlikely to be used in your org data